# Flutter Mobile Web Material Icons

Tags: mobile, flutter, fonts, flutter-web, google-material-icons

This is not an issue involving getting `Material Icons` to display on web but rather an issue getting `Material Icons` & fonts to display on *mobile web*.

I have included the following in my pubspec.yaml file

```
uses-material-design: true

fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf
```

In addition, I have dropped the ttf files for both fonts in the project's `assets/fonts` folder. When I run this using chrome, it works fine! However, when running this on an iPad pro in either Safari or Chrome, I get Times New Roman font and strange emojis in place of where the `Material Icons` should be.

I have verified that my `fontmanifest.json` file includes:

```
   {
        "family": "Roboto",
        "fonts": [
            {
                "asset": "assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "family": "MaterialIcons",
        "fonts": [
            {
                "asset": "assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am stumped. What is going on here?
[image: Weird icons 1]

[image: Should be navigated next but getting emojis]

Comment: I am not sure why this could be the case but everything seems to work fine on versions of iOS < 13.0. I don’t understand why this could be happening.

Comment: This issue has been fixed with the latest update to flutter. This was a bug. Closed